# How is the signal Multiplied with the Carrier in AM

Tags: wireless, amplitude-modulation, multiplier

In wireless transmission, via Amplitude modulation, we multiply the message signal by a carrier wave to get the modulated signal
$$x(t) = m(t) \times cos(\omega t)$$
Where \$m(t)\$ is the original message, \$\omega\$ is the frequency of the carrier wave and \$x(t)\$ is the modulated signal.

My question is, how does this multiplication take place in Hardware?

I am aware of chips like the [MPY 634](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/mpy634.pdf) which use a Gilbert Cell-based Architecture to achieve Multiplication and have a transfer function of the form
$$x_{out}=A\Big[\frac{(X_1-X_2)(Y_1-Y_2)}{SF}-(Z_1-Z_2)\Big]$$
Where the capitalised letters represent signals at 4 different terminals.

But this seems like an awfully complex, expensive and bulky solution for something that needs to be done often

Comment: There are simpler designs for a two-quadrant multiplier that are, I believe, used in AM transmitters. I know I've seen a way to use just a single JFET to do it, though I don't know if that's how it's done in actual modulators.

Comment: It multiplies (and subtracts) differential signals, its transfer function isn't quite complex at all. If you tie X2, Y2, Z1, Z2 to ground, the equation will be much simpler.

Comment: In frequency domain analysis, it is convolution ,not multiplication (as in time domain analysis), hence the iteration is not costly.

Comment: @seccpur but that would be true for a digital approach, right? I am not sure how we could think in terms of convolution in an Analog approach

Comment: @LongPham I was not referring to the complexity of the transfer function rather the Transistor based chip/circuit. But I think Andy aka's answer clears up the Hardware part too

Comment: For just goofing around in the lab, you can do it with a chopper. Run the chopper at carrier frequency. Modulate the "VCC" of the chopper. So, basically, imagine an oscillator running from a VCC that is varied by the message signal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But this seems like an awfully complex, expensive and bulky solution
>   for something that needs to be done often

Would you say the same about the Exclusive OR gate? It's a device that performs multiplication on digital signals and is the founding design for the Gilbert cell: -

[image]

[Picture source](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/375795/best-mixer-for-quadrature-fm-demodulator/375798#375798).

Would you say that using a Gilbert cell for an EXOR gate is "an awfully complex, expensive and bulky solution for something that needs to be done often"?

Of course if you wanted a really simple AM modulator you could use a couple of diodes and a filter and get something that was quite linear enough for AM. You could extend this to a four quadrant mixer using more diodes or you could go the whole hog and use a gilbert cell and filter.

Comment: Thank you this was insightful. Should I edit the question to remove the bias or let it stay?

Comment: My advice is let it stay because you might make my answer invalid with alterations.